# Pollard-Strassen Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, prime-numbers, factoring

I'm aware that the Pollard-Strassen algorithm can be used to find all prime factors of $n$ not exceeding $B$ in $O\big(n^{\epsilon} B^{1/2}\big)$ time. This is really useful because I need to find all factors less than $n^{1/3}$ to determine if n is squarefree, which could therefore theoretically be done in $O\big(n^{1/6+\epsilon}\big)$.

However I can't find anything more than a brief overview of the algorithm itself, let alone a worked example. Could anyone provide a detailed explanation or example, or reference to where I can find one? Additionally, I'm interested in other algorithms, if they exist, which provide all factors not exceeding $B=\big\lceil n^{1/3} \big\rceil$ quickly.

Comment: I was going to write it myself, but a quick google search lead me to [this](http://ideone.com/WR0hk). Unless the algorithm you wanted is not [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm)..

Comment: Actually those are both Pollard's rho algorithm. It's a probabilistic algorithm and also only works at finding factors of any size, not less than a specific bound.

Comment: I should add: you can see how it's difficult for me to track down this algorithm's details though! :) There are only a few mentions of it.

Comment: The method is also described in the book Prime Numbers by Crandall and Pomerance (2005), in the chapter 5.5 Polynomial evaluation method.

Comment: [This arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2608.pdf) appeared 4 years after your question. You may be interested in it and its references.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic idea of Strassen's factorization method is that if you have the product $f_i$ of a consecutive set of integers modulo the number to be factored $n$, and that set of integers contains one the factors of $n$, then $\mathrm{gcd}(f_i, n)$ will be greater than unity.  The trick then is to compute $f_i$ for non-overlapping sets of possible factors quickly.

Here is a brute-force example that shows how the 9th block of numbers reveals 293 as a factor of 1000009:

```
var n = (BigInteger)1000009;
var c = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Pow((double)n, 0.25));
var f = new BigInteger[c];
for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    f[i] = 1;
    var jmin = 1 + i * c;
    var jmax = jmin + c - 1;
    for (var j = jmin; j <= jmax; j++)
        f[i] = f[i] * j % n;
}
for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    var factor = BigInteger.GreatestCommonDivisor(f[i], n);
    if (factor != 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, factor = {1}", i, factor);
        break;
    }
}
```

The second for-loop takes $O(n^{1/4}\log n)$, and so the hard work of the algorithm is to compute $f_i$ in faster than the $O(n^{1/2})$ demonstrated in the first for-loop above.  How this is done is by using subproduct trees and multipoint evaluation.  Here is a [slide presentation](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/talks/factoring.pdf) that describes the details pretty well.  Also [this paper](http://algo.inria.fr/bostan/publications/BoGaSc07.pdf) (search for "Main algorithmic ideas") has a good high level overview of the algorithm.  Finally, subproduct trees are given a good treatment in this presentation, [Asymptotically fast
algorithms for modern
computer algebra](http://www.issac-conference.org/2010/assets/AFAMCA3.pdf).

Comment: Should that 0.25 be 0.34?